# Maximum number of local player stats in Xbox Live Services

Tags: xbox-live

I'm in the planning stage of a game and looking at using the Xbox Live services. I'm looking to have leaderboards in my game so I've been reading the documentation at:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/uwp/xbox-live/leaderboards-and-stats-2017/player-stats

The question I had around this, is there a max limit to the number of local (none featured) player stats you can store, that make up leaderboards?

The reason behind this is I want to show a leaderboard per level in the game but there could be hundreds of levels.

One forum post I spotted suggests that the limit might be 20:

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/Windowsdesktop/en-US/0b7b58ea-0bf1-43d5-ac4f-a51b5307e941/glitch-with-a-featured-stat?forum=xboxlivedev

Anyone able to shed some light on this limit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the limit is 20 stats.  We will make this more clear in our docs soon.  Thanks

Comment: Thanks for clarifying this. Did you have ideas on how I could have a leaderboard per level with potentially 100s of levels?

Comment: Unfortunately you can't do this with our current design.  We're looking at expanding our design to cover this scenario but nothing to announce at this time